# Google Places API Radar search - large radius search returning less results than smaller radius (inside the large)

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I do a google places api radar search with these parameters:

```
geo_point = {'lat' : '39.70856498268634', 'lng': '-8.722243487895712'}
radius = '12210'
```

This is my large circle and it returns 196 results.

I do another one with the following:

```
geo_point = {'lat' : '39.71196390304338', 'lng': '-8.764890291528587'}
radius = '5700'
```

This is my small circle and it returns 200 hits.

The issue is that the small circle is inside the big one. How can I get more results in my small circle/why do I not get all in the big one?

The types that I'm searching for are:

```
google_establishment_types = 'bar|cafe|casino|food|lodging|night_club|restaurant|stadium'
```